# How to force password re-entry for gpg with OSX keychain?

Tags: mac, encryption, passwords, gnupg

I'm using `gpg` on an OSX machine and I saved the password on Keychain for a long time.

I wanna re-enter the password to make sure it is the correct one, but I don't want to be locked out of `gpg` so I don't want to remove the entry from Keychain.

Any thoughts on allowing me to re-enter the password, without using Keychain, and without removing the password from Keychain?

Comment: Can't you just look at the password in Keychain itself & eliminate the guesswork?

Comment: @Tetsujin You are a gentleman and a scholar!

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome  :) I'll post an answer, just for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

From comments, as a frame-challenge rather than an answer to the question as asked…

It would be far simpler & less potentially dangerous to simply look up the existing password from Keychain Access, in Apps/Utilities.